# Парсинг attachments vk sdk

Tags: android, vkontakte-api

Записи со стены получаю так

```
VKParameters p = new VKParameters();
p.put(VKApiConst.COUNT,1);
p.put(VKApiConst.EXTENDED,1);

VKRequest r = VKApi.wall().get(p);

r.executeWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener(){
        public void onComplete(VKResponse r){
            super.onComplete(r);
                VKList<VKApiPost> posts = (VKList<VKApiPost>)r.parsedModel;   
                VKApiPost post = posts.get(0);  
                VKAttachments att = new VKAttachments();
                att = post.attachments;
    }
        public void onError(VKError e){
            super.onError(e);
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(),e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT); toast.show();

            //t.setText(e.errorMessage+e.errorCode);
        }
    });
```

Вопрос. Как правильно распарсить вложения

Comment: И что же у вас не получается? Берите атачменты из `att`

Comment: Можете объяснить подробнее, я не совсем понимаю. Нужно брать создавать модели VkApiPhoto, VkApiAudio и т.д. в зависимости от type?

Comment: это уже зависит от того, что вы с ними собираетесь делать

Comment: Если вам не сложно, можно привести немного кода, как именно из att что то берётся. Просто я, кроме getType() ничего не нашёл. Да, и я так понимаю att это массив.

Comment: VKAttachments  Это VKList из VKAttachment, которые являются базовым классом для VKApiAudio, и других типов аттачментов. сделайте Switch(attachment.getType), и работайте с ним в зависимости от его типа.

Comment: Может я не правильно понял, но VKApiAudio audio = new VKApiAudio();
     try {
     audio.parse(att.get(0).fields.getJSONObject("audio"));
     }
     catch(JSONException e){} не работает

Comment: их ненужно парсить, они уже отпарсены.  `VKApiAudio audio = (VKApiAudio )att.get(0);` предварительно проверьте, что тип у att.get(0) - аудио

Answer (score 0):

`VKAttachments` это массив разнотипных данных прикреплённых к посту. Все возможные типы описаны в доке. Парсить надо всё это отталкиваясь от типа данных примерно так:

```
for (VKAttachments.VKApiAttachment attachment : post.attachments) {
    if (attachment.getType().equals(VKApiConst.PHOTO)) {
        VKApiPhoto vkApiPhoto = (VKApiPhoto) attachment;
        Log.d("TAG", "small pthoto url: " + vkApiPhoto.photo_75);
    } else {
        Log.d("TAG", "attachment type is: " + attachment.getType());
    }
}
```

Comment: А как мне распарсить тип VkApiLink ? В VKApiConst ничего по link нету

Comment: @sviter-pro, ну, разрабы могли забыть добавить или ещё не добавили это в SDK. В таком случае сравнивайте просто со строкой `link` https://vk.com/dev/attachments_w?f=7.%20%D0%A1%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0%20(type%20%3D%20link)

Comment: Это понятно...я просто делаю все это через switch (attachment.getType()) и не догоняю какой мне поставить CASE

Comment: @sviter-pro, `case "link"`